# Reverse direction of css transition

Tags: css, css-transitions

When I hover over the anchor tag `<a>`, the `border-bottom` appears from top to bottom, how to reverse it so the `border-bottom` appear from bottom to top?

My current style:

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    transition: border .5s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover {
    border-bottom: 4px solid ;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bottom-padding decreasing in width, while the border increases would do the job.

```
a {
    padding-bottom:4px;
    display: inline-block;
}
a:hover {
    padding-bottom:0;
    border-bottom: 4px solid;
    transition: border .5s ease-in-out, padding .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZbR37/1/)